# Creating custom event handler for a RoutedEvent

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection, routed-events

Given a routed event identifier.

It is posible using reflection to create a Handler for that event?? (and of course add some code inside the handler).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a routed event identifier?

Answer (score 2):

There are only very limited number of truely Routed Events in Silverlight, they are all defined on the `UIElement` (except for `Loaded` on the `FrameworkElement`).

If its one of these to which you refer then rather than using reflection it would be easier to simply compare the provided `RoutedEvent` object with one of these few known ones.  Once established you will know which of the a limited number of possible signatures to use.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but have you looked into Func and Action delegates?